# Unit Testing for Code Coverage of Lambda Expression Condition

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda

I am using SonarQube for static code analysis and it raises an issue for not able to check for the alternate condition for the `if` condition for 3rd party library:

```
CountDownLatch connectedSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
zookeeper = new ZooKeeper(connectionString,this.sessionTimeout, event -> {
if (event.getState() == KeeperState.SyncConnected) {
      connectedSignal.countDown();
}});

connectedSignal.await();
```

Error from Sonarqube:
"1 more branches need to be covered by unit tests to reach the minimum threshold of 65.0% branch coverage." It's because I am not covering for the negative if condition in my unit test cases. Question is, how to generate a negative test case in my unit test case for the above if condition?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by passing the keeperstate to the method and setting different keeperstate from outside the method to test for negative if condition.

```
public ZooKeeper connect(String connectionString, 
        String sessionTimeout, KeeperState keeperState) {
        zookeeper = new ZooKeeper(connectionString,sessionTimeout, event -> {
                 if (event.getState() == keeperState) {
                    connectedSignal.countDown();
                 }
              }
        );

        connectedSignal.await(this.sessionTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```